# using Dynamic array of HANDLE(void*) with createThread(...)

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I'm a beginner in C and in threading in particular.

I need to `malloc` and use dynamic array of `HANDLE` that later would be used in `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

What I do now:

```
int i = 0 ;
HANDLE ThreadHandlers = (HANDLE)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE)* List->logicalLength);
```

Then in a loop:

```
while(curr!= NULL) 
{
    ThreadHandlers[i]= createtestThread((LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)executeTest,(TestStruct*)(curr->data),ThreadIds+i);

    curr = curr->next;
    //ThreadHandlers[i] = 
    i++;
}

WaitForMultipleObjects(
    List->logicalLength,
    ThreadHandlers,
    TRUE,       /* wait until all threads finish */
    INFINITE);
```

But when I try to compile, it I get:

> IntelliSense: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Which from my understanding is because `HANDLE` is typedef `void*`
and I cant do logic with `void*`.

1. What workaround can be done?
2. What is the right way to do that kind of programming? (waiting for unknown amount of threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
HANDLE  ThreadHandlers  =   (HANDLE)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE)* List->logicalLength);
```

Should be this:

```
HANDLE*  ThreadHandlers  =   (HANDLE*)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE) * List->logicalLength);
```

That above fix will resolve your compile problem with regards to WaitForMultipleObjects.

And while I'm here, this line looks suspicous:

```
ThreadHandlers[i]= createtestThread((LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)executeTest,(TestStruct*)(curr->data),ThreadIds+i);
```

I assume createtestthread is a wrapper for [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) or [_beginthreadex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx).  But if you have to explicitly cast your function explicitly to LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, you have probably done something wrong.  Remove the cast such that this line becomes:

```
ThreadHandlers[i]= createtestThread(executeTest,(TestStruct*)(curr->data),ThreadIds+i);
```

Then if that still leads to a new compiler error, fix the declaration of executeTest such that it's declared as follows:

```
DWORD __stdcall executeTest(void* pData);
```

Forcing a function of a different signature into CreateThread will lead to weird problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake in creation of array of handles, what you should do is:

```
HANDLE *ThreadHandlers = (HANDLE*)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE) * List->logicalLength);
```

As far as your second question goes, using `WaitForMultipleObjects` is the right way to wait for an unknown amount of threads. Depending on the situation, you could pass FALSE as third parameter if you want to wait only until one thread gets signaled, or pass some time-out interval as fourth argument if you want to stop waiting after a certain period.